# UILabel with custom UIEdgeInsets truncating in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have an UITableView with cells that contains an UILabel. 
The UILabel have a custom UIEdgeInset. I subclassed the UILabel and set the UIEdgeInsets like this:

```
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
    contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
    return contentSize
}
```

But the label gets truncated sometimes when I have more lines in the UILabel. 
I've already configured the row height to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** and set the **estimatedRowHeight**. Also the constraints are fine.
The problem seems to be when I'm setting the UIEdgeInsets since it works fine if I don't customize it.

Probably I should tell the cell to update the constraints after setting the insets, but I couldn't do this so far.

The constraints where added in storyboard. `Bottom`, `Top`, `Leading` and `Trailing` are related to the superview (UITableViewCell). All constants set to 0.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the code is as follows:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnswersCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerCell  
cell.answerLabel.text = alternatives[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

Comment: Lucas are you saying the label only gets truncated when you have more than one line in the label? By truncated I assume you mean cut off horizontally by the cell divider - i.e the cell is not expanding correctly to accommodate the extra line in the label. Is that correct?

Comment: Your label subclass behaves correctly for me with self-sizing table view cells, so you might want to share the code you use to setup your table view cells and subviews.

Comment: @thecloud_of_unknowing yes, the string is not fitting the view. It doesn't happen all the time when I have more than one line. It seems like it's not considering the new UIEdgeInsets I've set. So in some cases it fits fine, but other it might get truncated since it expects to have more width space left.

Comment: @jamesk there is not much code besides that. In `viewDidLoad` I set the `rowHeight` like this `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and also set the `estimatedRowHeight` like this `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120`. And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I only set the label text.

Comment: Just added more info, but it seems very simple and not related to the problem.

Comment: Your code should be working although it's much easier to wrap the label into another view.

Comment: maybe I'll end up doing that and stop trying to set the UIEdgeInsets. Anyway, it would be great to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe you should be overriding `textRect(forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)` instead of `drawText(in:)`

Answer (score 3):

Set these two properties of UILable from Attributes inspector section of storyboard

1. Lines to 0
2. Line break to word wrap

or you can also set these properties from code.

```
self.answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
self.answerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

and put below code in your UILable's subclass

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

@IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
@IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
@IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 20.0
@IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 5.0

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

}

try this.

Hope it will work for you..

Comment: In order for `intrinsicContentSize` to be useful on labels, you need to tell them where you want them to break: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

Answer (score 1):

During auto layout of a multiline label, UILabel does not compute its height using the width provided by its `intrinsicContentSize` property, but instead uses `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, which has not been adjusted to take account of your content insets.

The header file for UILabel provides the following comment for [`preferredMaxLayoutWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620534-preferredmaxlayoutwidth):

> // If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels

In your case, the desired value for `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is the auto layout width of the label (i.e. the width of the table view cell) less any left and right content insets. The most practical way to set that property is in your table view cell subclass, because that is the most straightforward place to access the width of the table view cell during auto layout.

When performing auto layout for self-sizing table view cells, UITableView calls [`systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefitting) on each cell.  (See [WWDC 2014 Session 226](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/226/).) The fitting size passed to that method is the width of the table view with a zero height, and the horizontal fitting priority is `UILayoutPriorityRequired`.

So, override that method and set the desired value for `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`:

```
//  AnswerCell.swift

@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: AnswerLabel!

override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
    answerLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = targetSize.width - answerLabel.insets.left - answerLabel.insets.right
    return super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)
}
```

The effect is that, in computing its height during auto layout, UILabel uses a value of `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` that has been adjusted for your content insets, which ensures that UITableView receives the correct heights for its cells.

**Addendum**

Alternatively, instead of all of the above, you could simply change the constraints on your label to inset the whole label, either directly in the content view of the table view cell or by embedding it in another subview of the content view.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr The value of `intrinsicContentSize` isn't used when drawing the text. Horizontal space is reserved by insetting the rect passed to `drawText(in:)`. Although `intrinsicContentSize` was not responsible for the OP's problem, it was still incorrect—it returned a width larger than the width of the label's super view. Be civil, please.

Comment: `intrinsicContentSize` determines the view's alignment size, i.e. unless `alignmentRectInsets` is non-zero, the view's bounds size. When the view insets its bounds before drawing, then `intrinsicContentSize` needs to account for that.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr You're right. I wrote that part of the answer before setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, which meant that (at that time) `super.intrinsicContentSize` returned a width that appeared to account for the content insets (being the width of the parent cell). But once `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is set so that it accounts for content insets, `super.intrinsicContentSize` returns a width that excludes the insets and, as you say, requires adjustment. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

I subclassed my Label like this:

```
class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    var topInset: CGFloat = 0
    var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0
    var leftInset: CGFloat = 0
    var rightInset: CGFloat = 0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
            contentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
            contentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
            return contentSize
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's the `get` that's missing.

Comment: Actually it's not that. When you have a read-only computed property, you can simplify it by removing the `get` keyword and its braces.

Comment: Well, this label works fine for me. All I need to do is set the variables (top, bottom, left, right insets) and it's good to go